# What is the difference between unique form algorithms and unique of the list container?

Tags: c++, list, unique, std

Can i perform the unique algorithm on a list? And if so, where is the difference to the unique function of the list container?

Is the following code equivalent?

```
std::list<int> l;
//add some values to list
l.unique();
```

and

```
std::list<int> l;
//add some value to list
std::unique(l.begin(), l.end());
```

Comment: [They're not the same](http://rextester.com/DPDX45285)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[They're not the same](http://rextester.com/DPDX45285).

[`std::list::unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/unique) removes all consecutive duplicate elements from the container.
This is what you probably want.

[`std::unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique)... well...

> Removing is done by shifting the elements in the range in such a way that elements to be erased are overwritten. Relative order of the elements that remain is preserved and the physical size of the container is unchanged. Iterators pointing to an element between the new logical end and the physical end of the range are still dereferenceable, but the elements themselves have unspecified values. A call to unique is typically followed by a call to a container's erase method, which erases the unspecified values and reduces the physical size of the container to match its new logical size.

Answer (score 2):

> Is the following code equivalent?

No, it's not. `std::list::unique` will remove all consecutive duplicates, but `std::unique` has no way of doing this generically for all containers. The algorithm will rearrange the container such that the non-removed ones are at the beginning and give you back an iterator that you should erase from.

These two are equivalent (at least in terms of what the resulting list looks like, though not in the steps taken to get there, the requirements on the type, or the effects on iterator validation):

```
l.unique();
l.erase(
    std::unique(l.begin(), l.end()), 
    l.end());
```

The latter is also referred to as the Erase-Remove idiom (though in this case we're using unique and not remove)

Comment: They are only mostly equivalent. One relinks nodes, the other uses move assignment. Hence the requirements on the type and the effects on iterator validity are different.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the algorithms in `<algorithm>`, are generic algorithms which works on iterators. In conclusion, these algorithms cannot make advantage from the way the container is build up.

The STL however also adds member functions to their containers which are less generic, though can take advantage from the container structure.

An example: `std::find(map.cbegin(), map.cend(), element)` will go over all elements to find the given element, while `map.find(element)` can make use of the tree-structure. This reduces a `linear` algorithm to a `log(n)`.

The same strategy is added to `std::list`, as 'moving' an element is a std::list is no more than changing the links in the list, this can be a lot more performant than moving/copying the content of the elements.

So, for `std::list<int>`, I don't expect much a different, though if you store expensive classes in the list, you will notice the difference.

PS: std::unique doesn't remove elements, it moves it to the back and returns a new 'end', use std::remove (or std::list::remove) to remove the elements